# Making lisp evaluator using C macros

Tags: c, macros, scheme, lisp

I was reading chapters on C macros system and found that I can define some simple lisp-like evaluator.

```
#define add(x,y) ((x)+(y))
#define mult(x,y) ((x)*(y))
#define sub(x,y) ((x)-(y))
#define eval(x) main(){printf("%d\n",(x));}

eval( mult (sub(10,2) ,  add(6,2)))
```

Of course this is just a joke, but is there opportunity to make full scheme evaluator using macro system?

Comment: Doesn't look like lisp to me...

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a small C-like subset implemented with macros.

To call anything `LISP` you need fully parenthesized [Polish prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) notation. eg. in C you would write `5 + 5` while in LISP you would write `(+ 5 5)`. In C you might write `10 + 3 + 6 - 1` and in Lisp you would write `(- (+ 10 3 6) 1)`

If you are interested in how you might want to implement a LISP language you might be interested in Peter Michaux' [Bootstrap Scheme](http://michaux.ca/articles/scheme-from-scratch-bootstrap-v0_1-integers) and then try to create your own. It's a very nice exercise that teaches you the wonderful world of LISP and how to make an interpreter/compiler (depending on what you end up doing) and you get better in both LISP and the language you choose to implement it in.

If you are unfamiliar with LISP languages you might need to learn a little LISP before you start. I recommend Paul Grahams essay [The roots of LISP](http://www.paulgraham.com/rootsoflisp.html) and if you have time you might want to do all the [video lectures of SICP](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/) which are done by the wizards themselves. For a more Common Lisp approach you might be interested in [Land of Lisp](http://www.landoflisp.com/).

Comment: Implementing MLISP or RLISP, both without prefix notation, would already be a start. For example the Computer Algebra System REDUCE is written in RLISP.

Answer (score 1):

No, macros aren't turing complete.  C++ templates, on the other hand, are turing complete, and it is a strictly functional language, but something vaguely like lisp could be written with it to create functions at compile time.  But, it could have slow compilation that uses a lot of memory.